# JSON Javascript Parsing String

Tags: javascript, json

If:

```
JSON.stringify(data)
```

Returns:

```
{"data":{"url":"http://www.google.com"}}
```

How do I access the url?

I tried

```
data.url
data[0].url
```

Comment: Stringify *afterwards*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to parse the data back into a JavaScript object:

```
JSON.parse(data).data.url;
```

When in JSON format, it's just a string.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `data.data.url`.   Your variable is called data, but your first entry is also called data.

Answer (score 0):

```
data.data.url
```

your object is called data, it contains an object called data which has a url property.